# Support cookies and Enable Javascript to scrape the partner site?

Tags: php, browser, guzzle6, guzzle

Here the error return by the partner site

> To continue, your browser must support cookies and JavaScript must be
> activated. To continue your browser has to accept cookies and has to
> have JavaScript enabled.
>
> Here the code i am using

```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $proxySetting=[
                'proxy' => 'socks://' . $proxyDetail['server'] . ':' . $proxyDetail['port'],
                'verify' => false,
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ' .
                '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,' .
                'image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Cookie' => ["mobile.LOCALE=de; Domain=.mobile.de; Expires=Thu, 02-Jul-2020 03:38:39 GMT; Path=/"],
            'Referer' => 'http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar.xml',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => 1,
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
            ];
        $response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            $url,
            $proxySetting
        );
```

Comment: have a read here: https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/

Comment: Is an error being returned by the server? If so what is it?  What is the expected result?  What is the remote server trying to do that requires javascript to be enabled?  If the remote server requires a javascript enabled client, you sir are using the wrong tool for the job (unless you were to develop a custom middleware that requests all javascript, inlines it and then pushes it through php-v8 php's javascript extension).  Guzzle has no support for parsing javascript.

Comment: @ShaunBramley They just return a message "need cookies support and enable javascript". How to create middle ware that request all javascript? How we can send it back to get the scrapped html from the page?

Comment: Information on creating Guzzle middleware can be found at http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html#middleware  and within the source code itself. Your custom middleware will have to perform the same thing that Chrome / FF / Edge do.  Parse original response, find external files, make subsequent requests, inject those responses, pass to javascipt engine...